# Update cell update without scroll to top

Tags: tabulator

I have an issue where on updating a cell with cellEdited, The page jumps back to the top of the page when the mutator or formatter is called.

I've tried setting table.redraw(false) and then the formatter/mutator doesn't seem to do anything.

When a user updates the proficiency level the formatter or mutator should add a button if it's above 3. It works perfectly. However it jumps to the top of the screen.

Any help appreciated.

```
var evidenceMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component){


    skillsTable.redraw(false);

    var claimedProficiency = data.Proficiency;
    var skillClaimed = data.SkillID;
    var Evidence = data.Evidence;
    var memberID = $("#user").data("memberid");

    if (claimedProficiency >= 3 )  {

        // has provided evidence
        if (Evidence == 1) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs btn-slim evidence" href="#" id="'+ skillClaimed + '" onclick="openEvidenceModal(this, this.id, '+ memberID +')"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle cssover"></i> Edit Evidence </a>';
        } else { // needs to provide
            return '<a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs btn-slim evidence" href="#" id="'+ skillClaimed + '" onclick="openEvidenceModal(this, this.id, '+ memberID +')"> <i class="fas fa-times-circle cssover"></i> Add Evidence </a>';
        }

    } else {

       // cell.getElement().style.color = "#CCD1D1";
        //cell.getElement().style.fontStyle ="italic";
       // cell.getElement().style.fontSize = "0.75em";
        return '&nbsp; No Evidence Needed';
    }



}

function complianceTick(cell) {

    var isCompliant = cell.getData().Compliance;
    var Evidence = cell.getData().Evidence;
    var claimedProficiency = cell.getData().Proficiency;

    // style all with sucesss and only change if we need to
    cell.getElement().style.color = "#33CC66";
    cell.getElement().style.fontSize = "0.85em";
    cell.getElement().style.fontStyle = "italic";


    if (claimedProficiency >= 3 )  {

        if (Evidence == '1') {
            return '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>';

        } else {
            cell.getElement().style.color = "#FF0000";
            cell.getElement().style.fontSize = "0.85em";
            cell.getElement().style.fontWeight = "bold";

            return '<i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>';
        }

    } else {
            return '';
    }

}


var skillsTable = new Tabulator("#SkillsTable", {
    index: "SkillID",
    height:"100%",
    headerVisible:false,

    autoResize:true,
    layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
    groupBy:"SkillCatID",
    groupHeader: groupMaker,
    initialSort:[             //set the initial sort order of the data
        {column:"RowOrder", dir:"asc"}
    ],
    columns:[  //define the table columns
        {title:"", field:"SkillID", visible:false},
        {title:"Skill", field:"SkillName", visible:true, headerSort:false, formatter: skillName},
        {title:"", field:"SkillCatID", visible:false},
        {title:"", field:"SkillCatName", visible:false},
        {title:"My Level", field:"Proficiency", visible:true, editor:inputEditor, formatter:prof, width:"7%", headerSort:false, align:"center",
            cellEdited:function(cell, row, success){  // EDITING FUNCTION

                var $value = cell.getValue();
                var $field = cell.getField();
                var $row = cell.getRow();
                var $id = $row.getData().SkillID;

                var integer = parseInt($value, 10);
                if ($value != "" && integer < 5 && integer >= 0) {

                    // update record
                    updateRecord($id, $field, $value, $row);

                    //$row.update({"Proficiency" : $value});
                    //$row.update({"Evidencer" : $value});

                    skillsTable.updateRow($id, {id:$id,"Proficiency":$value});
                    skillsTable.updateRow($id, {id:$id,"Evidencer":$value});

                } else {
                    cell.restoreOldValue();

                    if ($value != "") {
                        alert ("Values should be between 0 and 4, the cell has been restored to its previous value.")
                    }
                }

            },
        },
        {title:"Target", field:"MinLevel", visible:false, headerSort:false},
        {title:"", field:"Proficiency", visible:true, formatter: skillDec, headerSort:false},
        {title:"Evidence", field:"Evidencer", visible:true, hozAlign:"center", formatter: evidenceCell, mutator: evidenceMutator, width:"10.5%", headerSort:false},
        {title:"", field:"RowOrder", visible:false, sorter:"number"},
        {title:"disc", field:"DisciplineID", visible:false, headerFilter:true}
    ],
});
```

**UPDATE**

I think I've narrowed down the issue to the formatter:

````
```
function evidenceCell(cell, formatterParms, onRendered) {

    var claimedProficiency = cell.getData().Proficiency;
    var skillClaimed = cell.getData().SkillID;
    var Evidence = cell.getData().Evidence;
    var memberID = $("#user").data("memberid");

    if (claimedProficiency >= 3 )  {

        // has provided evidence
        if (Evidence == 1) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-xs btn-slim evidence" href="#" id="'+ skillClaimed + '" onclick="openEvidenceModal(this, this.id, '+ memberID +')"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle cssover"></i> Edit Evidence </a>';
        } else { // needs to provide
            return '<a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs btn-slim evidence" href="#" id="'+ skillClaimed + '" onclick="openEvidenceModal(this, this.id, '+ memberID +')"> <i class="fas fa-times-circle cssover"></i> Add Evidence </a>';
        }

    } else {

        cell.getElement().style.color = "#CCD1D1";
        cell.getElement().style.fontStyle ="italic";
        cell.getElement().style.fontSize = "0.75em";
        return 'No Evidence Needed';
    }

}
```
````

It looks like the issue is with the cell.getData(). It seems to trigger the scroll to the top of page. I think it may be a bug with the newer version. Testing 4.2 and it seems to not be an issue. However, I have issues with modals going to the top of the page with the older version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the virtual DOM. In my case I can luckily turn it off by using the following:

```
virtualDom:false,
```

I'm not sure this would be a good fix for people with hundreds of rows.